# Fetch Javascript variable in source section using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I have a series of interconnected pages to test using JMeter. The problem is that the initial page has a Javascript variable in source section which is more of a session variable. This variable is passed in the URL for subsequent pages.

So basically I would like to fetch this javascript variable when I load the initial page from the source section and pass it to next URL(s).

Is there a way I can achieve this using JMeter.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to see the session variable in the response of initial page?
(in view result tree listener)

If yes, then correlate this value and pass the variable in to next request (use regular expression extractor for fetching the value, still if you are finding some issue in correlating the value than please share the response of first request over here so that I can provide you regx for that)

Answer (score 0):

People mostly [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) to fetch dynamic values from previous responses, in general the process looks like:

1. Add Regular Expression Extractor as a child of the request which returns desired data
2. Use [Perl5-style regular expression](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) to match what you're looking for
3. Provide a template to choose match group - ususally `$1$` if you looking for a single value
4. Provide a reference name to refer the extracted value, i.e. `foo`
5. Use extracted value as `${foo}` where required

You can visualise JMeter Variables using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination.

The easiest way to debug your regular expressions is using View Results Tree listener in "RegExp Tester mode"

[image: View Results Tree - RegExp Tester]

See [How to debug your Apache JMeter script](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article for more information on troubleshooting your JMeter test.